# A persons potential

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

It says that a persons potential keeps rising as his spiritual level rises. If so, how does a person reach his potential?

Comment: What "it" says? Can you point to a source?

Comment: I think he is referring to "cal hagadol meichaveiro yitzro gadol heimenu" but is misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 2):

Potential is a tool and perhaps an analog to how one is doing in his service of Hashem. If one reached his potential, for him that would be perfection and he would have no true purpose left in life. The goal is to strive to fulfill the potential and never stop.

Answer (score 1):

the potential referred to  is not intellectual or accumulative. It is a level of relationship with G-D and depends upon one's Shoresh Haneshama. To Expect Ruach Hakodesh from piety means not assessing one's potential properly. In deed there is no limit to one's maasim.However,one cannot create a temperment that another has. If you need sleep, don't try what the Vilner Gaon did.Nor should a person try to fast etc...
A good madrich for those without a Rebbe is Hilchos Dayos of the Rambam-after one has read the first 6 prakim of the Shmoneh Prakim le'HoRambam.